# Request.exceptions.InvalidSchema: адаптеры подключения не найдены?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, bs4

Всех приветствую ! Я парсю дату с [этого ресурса](https://kapital.kz/news/). Вот эту дату[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой код имеется:

```
# < Получаем ссылки и дату с главной страницы где берутся ссылки.
def get_resource_links(resource_page, datetimes_main_rule, links_rule, resource_domain):
    resource_links = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resource_page,'lxml')
    resource_links_blocks = soup.find_all(links_rule[0], {links_rule[1]: links_rule[2]})
    main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetimes_main_rule[0], {datetimes_main_rule[1]: datetimes_main_rule[2]})
    if (len(datetimes_main_rule) == 3):
        main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetimes_main_rule[0], {datetimes_main_rule[1]: datetimes_main_rule[2]})
    for resource_link_block in resource_links_blocks:
        a_tag = resource_link_block .find("a")
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            resource_links.append(resource_domain + link)
    return (resource_links, main_page_datetime)
```

В этом участке кода я парсю дату:

```
main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetimes_main_rule[0], {datetimes_main_rule[1]: datetimes_main_rule[2]})
    if (len(datetimes_main_rule) == 3):
        main_page_datetime = soup.find(datetimes_main_rule[0], {datetimes_main_rule[1]: datetimes_main_rule[2]})
```

При запуске кода такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 142, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 123, in call_all_func
    item_page = get_html(resource_link, encodings_rule)
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/parser.py", line 16, in get_html
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://kapital.kz/finance/81046/nacvalyuta-k-dollaru-ukrepilas-na-1-2-tenge.html', 'https://kapital.kz/real_estate/81045/baspana-hit-kazahstancy-kupili-svyshe-13-tysyach-kvartir.html', 'https://kapital.kz/finance/81044/obem-potrebitelskih-kreditov-dostig-3-8-trln-tenge.html', 'https://kapital.kz/economic/80977/ayan-erenov-eksportnaya-orientirovannost-v-strany-ca-daet-rezultaty.html', 'https://kapital.kz/business/80961/kak-razvivaet-biznes-edinstvennyj-proizvoditel-bytovoj-himii-zko.html', 'https://kapital.kz/gosudarstvo/80974/ao-i-too-osobennosti-deyatelnosti-i-regulirovaniya.html', 'https://kapital.kz/business/80954/kazahstanec-vyvel-na-rynok-innovacionnyj-gel.html', 'https://kapital.kz/gosudarstvo/81043/sotrudnichestvo-s-oae-i-rossiej-rejting-kazahstana-podderzhka-proizvoditelej.html', 'https://kapital.kz/tehnology/81042/v-moody-s-predskazali-standartizaciyu-tehnologii-blokchejn.html', 'https://kapital.kz/world/81041/torgovlya-kitaya-i-ssha-sokratilas-na-14.html', 'https://kapital.kz/economic/81040/kak-otlichayutsya-ceny-na-bilety-v-kino-v-kazahstane-i-mire.html', 'https://kapital.kz/world/81039/palata-lordov-utverdila-proekt-o-perenose-brexit.html', 'https://kapital.kz/finance/81038/mfo-operezhayut-banki-po-tempam-rosta-kreditovaniya.html', 'https://kapital.kz/world/81037/telegram-razreshil-polzovatelyam-skryvat-nomer-telefona.html', 'https://kapital.kz/gosudarstvo/81036/chto-bolshe-vsego-chitali-na-etoj-nedele-na-kapital-kz.html']'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Исходя из traceback ошибка кроется в этом участке кода:

```
def get_html(url, encodings_rule):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if (len(encodings_rule) == 1):
            r.encoding = encodings_rule[0]
            return r.text
    except TooManyRedirects as e:
        print(f'{url} : {e}')
```

Comment: А в `url` случаем не список с url вы передали?

Comment: @gil9red,я не понял ваш вопрос,можете переформулировать ?

Comment: Выведите `print("url: ", url)`, чтобы убедиться что там находится валидная строка - url

Comment: @gil9red,ссылка валидная это я проверил

Comment: А ошибка говорит, что у вас в `url` хранится **список**: `['https://kapital.kz/finance/81046/nacvalyuta-k-dollaru-ukrepilas-na-1-2-tenge.html', 'https://kapital.kz/real_estate/81045/baspana-hit-kazahstancy-kupili-svyshe-13-tysyach-kvartir.html', 'https://kapital.kz/finance/81044/obem-potrebitelskih-kreditov-dostig-3-8-trln-tenge.html', ...`

Comment: @gil9red,вот результат принта `url:  https://kapital.kz/news/`

Comment: Найдите `item_page = get_html(resource_link, encodings_rule)` и выведите `resource_link`

Comment: @gil9red,сделал вывод в итоге у меня `resource_link` содержит массив из ссылок

Comment: Об этом я и писал все это время :)

Comment: @gil9red, благодарю вас ! То есть значит что в  `r = requests.get(url)` принимает  массив ? Правильно ли я вас понял ? И если это так, то я же могу перебором с помощью цикла эту проблему решить?

Comment: Думаю да, в `requests.get` можно только строку указывать. Если у вас список `url`, то самостоятельно в цикле переберите его

Comment: @gil9red,теперь чтобы вас отблагодарить оформите  пожалуйста ответ.Чтобы я мог его указать верным и проголосовать за ваш ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тексту ошибки, в `requests.get` (функция `get_html`) вместо строки с `url` попадал **список** с url.

Чтобы перебрать список `url` нужно вручную перебрать его в цикле.

Получится что-то вроде такого:

```
...
for url in resource_links:
    item_page = get_html(url, encodings_rule)
    ...
```